# Semantical Role of Genitive / Значение родительного падежа

Tags: лингвистика

The case has two primary semantical roles:

1. possessive, e.g. "Невинность мусульман" (here "мусульман" denotes possessors) and
2. partitive, e.g. "Не надо дураков" (here 'дураков' denotes partial negation).

What are the other semantical roles of Genitive in Russian?

У падежа есть две основные грамматические роли (далее - "семантические аспекты"):

1. притяжательно-принадлежностное значение, например "Невинность мусульман" (здесь "мусульман" означает обладателей) и
2. парциальное, например "Не надо дураков" (здесь 'дураков' означает частичное отрицание).

Каковы другие семантические аспекты родительного падежа в русском?

Comment: В примере №2 не парциальное значение, и не частичное отрицание, а обычное использование родительного падежа в роли дополнения при глаголе (или при любом другом сказуемом) с отрицанием, как в этом предложении, "Я не читал этой книги". Парциальное значение - это "налейте мне чая".

Comment: В примере №2 именно парциальное отрицание (ср. с использованием "Я не читал эту книгу" и "Налейте мне чай", где действие направлено на весь объект полностью).

Comment: Вы неверно используете термин "аспектология".

Comment: Речь идет о семантических аспектах. Создан новый тэг.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an easy task to define the semantic role of the Genitive case.

> In a number of Indo-European languages, the genitive case exhibits a great variety of semantic functions, expressing meanings as diverse as the agent of an action and the constituent material (out of which something is made), the possessor and the Standard of comparison. Some of these meanings denote more concrete relationships while others denote more abstract ones between the modifier and the modifying noun.

From an abstractionist approach,

> One of the inevitable conclusions of the general/abstract analysis, is that the possible interpretations of the genitive morpheme should be indefinite, given that there are infinite and indefinite imaginable contexts and noun-noun combinations. This would seem to suggest that there is (are) really no conventional meaning(s) attached to the genitive morpheme, other than, that is, a very abstract meaning which, depending on the context, can be realized in a thousand different ways.

Trying to find the general meaning of the Genitive case in Russian, Jakobson came to a conclusion that it is used to

> indicate the limit of the referent's involvement in the content of the utterance

You might be interested in reading this linguistic work on the topic: *[The meanings of the genitive: A case study in semantic structure and semantic change](http://typo.uni-konstanz.de/ocs-uploads/conferences/1/schedConfs/1/papers/reading-list/cogl.1991.2.2.149.pdf)*. All of the above citations come from there.

That said, Russian genitive has a wide variety of meanings probably comparable to the genitive of Classical Greek which is among the languages with the largest number of genitive meanings.

Looking at the classification provided in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case), I'll give you some examples:

- possession

  - inalienable possession ("глаза кошки", "вес слона")
  - alienable possession ("платье моей мамы")
  - relationship indicated by the noun being modified ("муж Марии")
- composition (partly similar in meaning to the partitive case in other languages):

  - substance ("кусок мяса", "кубик сахара")
  - elements ("группа людей")
- participation in an action:

  - as an agent (the subjective genitive) ("любовь матери")
- origin ("жители Рима")
- reference ("столица России")
- description ("человек чести", "день возмездия")

More categories can be added to the list and some categories can be further expanded to zoom in on more detaled meanings. Also, take a look at the section on [Slavic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case#Slavic_languages) in the above mentioned Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

Процитирую Вам Розенталя. Это не является прямым ответом на ваш вопрос, но, возможно, с Вашими познаниями в языках поможет Вам самостоятельно понять некоторые ответы, благодаря тому, что приведено множество примеров использования:

В родительном падеже возможны вариантные окончания в сочетаниях типа стакан чаю – стакан чая, много народу – много народа. Форма на -у(ю), с присущим ей разговорным оттенком, допускается в следующих случаях:

1)      у имен существительных с вещественным значением при указании на количество, т.е. для обозначения части целого, например: стакан чаю (ср.: вкус чая), килограмм сахару (ср.: сладость сахара); достать воску, керосину, клею, лаку, мелу, скипидару, тесу; купить гороху, жиру, луку, меду, перцу, рису, сыру; то же с ударным окончанием: килограмм песку, достать чесноку, прибавить кипятку, прикупить миндалю.

С окончанием -у употребляются существительные, имеющие в своем составе ударный уменьшительный суффикс и ударение на окончании во всех косвенных падежах: выпить кваску, коньячку, чайку, поесть медку, сахарку, сырку, чесночку (выпить чайка, съесть сырка употребить невозможно), а также некоторые существительные с безударным уменьшительным суффиксом: выпить кефирчику, достать бензинчику;

2)      у собирательных существительных с тем же количественным значением: много народу (ср.: история народа); всякого сброду понаехало;

3)      у имен существительных отвлеченных, входящих в состав разговорных устойчивых сочетаний: наделать шуму, нагнать страху, наговорить вздору;

4)      в некоторых фразеологических оборотах: без году неделя, без роду и племени, дать маху, добиться толку, задать перцу, конца-краю нет, много шуму из ничего, нашего полку прибыло, не до смеху, поддать жару, прибавить шагу, с глазу на глаз, с кругу спиться, с миру по нитке, сбить с толку, спору нет, только и разговору, что есть духу, упустить из виду, тридцать лет от роду, беситься с жиру, умереть с голоду, танцевать до упаду, говорить без умолку, ни разу, ни слуху ни духу, ни шагу дальше и др.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, что я имел в виду.